# how to join two tables and get null values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables `Color`, `Shade`, and `Activity`:

Color:

```
id     color
---    ------
1       red
2       green
3       white



Shade

   id      shade    
  ----    ------- 
     1      light    
     2        dark
```

Activity:

```
user_id  shade_id  color_id
------   --------  --------
1          1        1
1          1        2
2          2        3
```

I am using mysql and can easily find the colors belonging to a user by a specific shade:

```
select c.name, 'assigned'
from color c
left join activity a on c.id = a.color_id
where a.shade_id = 1 and a.user_id = 1;
```

The above will give me:

```
Color  Status
-----  -------
red    assigned
green  assigned
```

**Question**

However, I want a list of all the colors with `assigned` for ones that belong to the her and `not assigned` for ones that don't.

So I would want

```
Color       Status
-----       -------
red         assigned
green       assigned
white       not assigned
```

Comment: Because of `a.shade_id = 1 and a.user_id = 1` clause using `left join` is same is using `join`, that's why you don't get colors which are not assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Color, B.shade_id Status
FROM Color A LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
                      FROM Activity WHERE shade_id = 1) B
     ON A.id = B.color_id
```

`NULL` represents unassigned.

Answer (score 1):

Join it with `shade` table as well, like below

```
select name,
case when shade is null then 'Not Assigned'
else 'Assigned'
end as Status
from
(select c.name, s.shade
from color c
left join shade s on c.id = s.id
left join activity a on c.id = a.color_id
where a.shade_id = 1 and a.user_id = 1;
) tab
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.name, 'assigned'
FROM Color c
LEFT JOIN Activity a
ON c.id = a.color_id
WHERE a.shade_id = 1 AND a.user_id = 1
UNION
SELECT c.name, 'unassigned'
FROM Color c
WHERE c.id NOT IN (
  SELECT a.color_id
  FROM Activity a
  WHERE a.shade_id = 1 AND a.user_id = 1);
```

Or, merging the two other answers (I liked both more than mine, to be honest):

```
SELECT Color, CASE WHEN B.shade_id IS NULL THEN 'Not Assigned'
ELSE 'Assigned'
END AS Status
FROM Color A
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * FROM Activity WHERE shade_id = 1) B
ON A.id = B.color_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move your `schade_id = 1` condition from the `where` clause to the join condition (`ON...`)

```
select c.name, 'assigned'
from color c
  left join activity a 
         on c.id = a.color_id 
        and a.shade_id = 1;
```